# Woocommerce | Subscription Items - Buttons and next payment field not working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having trouble with Wordpress's Woocommerce.

For some reason the buttons are not working nor if I change the next payment date and save is working.

This section is under: `WooCommerce > Subscription > Edit Subscription`.

On the page, it's under: Subscription Items & Billing Schedule.

In the screenshot attached, in the highlighted long red box, those buttons are not working when you click on them.

The highlighted red box on the upper right, when you change the date and update, the date does not save. I've made sure everything is up to date, even Wordpress itself.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you have Subscriptions you should contact Woo's support. It can be slow to get a response because they have a million tickets but you'll eventually get an answer. Though the first thing they will tell you to do is to check against a default theme. 7/10 it's a theme conflict. They'll also ask you to temporarily disable other plugins to rule out a plugin conflict. So rule those out first before contacting them to speed things up.

Comment: Hi, 

It does seem to be a plugin issue - Plugin: Gravity Forms.

This was the last plugin installed before the issue started.

Once I deactivated the plugin, it the buttons and payment date started to work as normal.

What solution would you say is best here?

Please advise. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: FIXED!

I updated that plugin in my Wordpress, as I saw that it was the 2nd latest plugin - once updating it to the latest version, everything is working smoothly now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED! I updated that plugin in my Wordpress, as I saw that it was the 2nd latest plugin - once updating it to the latest version, everything is working smoothly now.